# extract url from string using regex

Tags: php, regex

my string holds the pattern "a[main/subfolder],b", i need to extract string between [], so this is what i do

```
<?php
    $bs=explode(",",$breadcrumb);

    foreach($bs as $b):
        preg_match('/\[(.*?)\]/', $b, $a);

        if(!empty($a)&&trim($a[1])!=""){

            $b=substr($b,0,strpos($b,'['));

            $b="<a href=\"".site_url()."en/".$a[1]."\">".$b."</a>";
        }

?>
<span>&gt;</span>
<?php
    echo $b;
    endforeach;
?>
```

i am able to extract pattern such as "a[path],b" but not "a[main/subfolder],b", so i changed the regex pattern to `/\[(.*?)(\/)*\]/` but not working. where did i do wrong?

Comment: i am new to regex, although i take up some tutorial on that, but still find hard to master it. sorry if this problem sounds easy, but i have been spending hour to find out the solution

Comment: just try:  `/\[([^\]]*?)\]/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this regex:

`/\[([^\]]*?)\]/`

`[^\]]` will match all characters excepte `]`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jQ1nO9/1)

```
\[([^\]]*?)\]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/V258PJNvq4lfP_n1)